# Past simple in the second conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, past-simple

In the Friends TV show Phoebe complains about her bank and five hundred extra dollars in her account. She explains that she can't spend that money in the following words:

> Let's say I bought a really great pair of shoes, do you know what I'd hear with every step **I took**.

Why does she use past simple saying *I took*? I thought it had to be like *with every step I'd <strike>took</strike> take* in the second conditional.

Could someone please explain what I'm missing and point me out to a rule or something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *I'd took* is ungrammatical - the past perfect is *I had (I'd) taken.* But the past perfect is not required in conditional phrases like this.

*If I could take a seaside holiday, as soon as I arrived I would go and look at the sea.* (not *as soon as I had arrived).*

Comment: Thank you, so this actually means that everything in this type of conditional should be in the past? And since *I took* here is even more past than *I'd hear* we use either past perfect or just past simple (because we can understand the order of the events from the sentence), right? Sorry if what I'm saying is quite wrong, I'm just trying to explain this in my own words

Comment: I don't think it will help you to worry about the logic of the order in which things happened.  You just have to accept that this is how such sentences are written.

Comment: So to be clear if I speak about past in unreal future I can safely use past simple, right?

Comment: You are not speaking about the past, but about a hypothetical situation.

Comment: I just want to understand the difference between *I'd hear* and *I took* in the sentence. For me *I took* seems like a past event happened in unreal hypothetical situation. That's why we use past simple, but I may be wrong.

Comment: "I  _would hear_ [it] with every step that I _took_." In very formal language, I think you could say "that I _were to take_". I can't explain it, it's just the way the conditional works.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've just noticed a typo in my question - I wrote *I'd took*, but really meant *I would take*, so could the sentence be like *with every step I would take*?

Comment: You were a long time noticing that, since it was the first thing I corrected!  You might say that, but _I took_ is much more natural.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about that. I saw that you corrected it, but I misunderstood your correction. Anyway, thank you very much for your help. It was very useful!